# Issues with resizing my UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, image-resizing, uicollectionviewlayout

I am currently trying to resize my cell within my CollectionView. I have already implemented the dataSource, CollectionViewDelegate and CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

***This is the code I have for the latter:***

```
   extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
     return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

**The problem is** that when I head over to my storyboard and select my CollectionView and then go to the Attributes Inspector to switch "Estimate Size" from "Automatic" to "None," I would get three columns after running my app [Image #1].

[image]

**The result I am looking** for is to be able to have one middle column with a bigger cell as I show on Image #2.

[image]

Has anybody dealt with this problem before?

Comment: You should probably be using a `UITableView` if you want only one column. Is there a reason you're using a collection view?

Comment: Yes, sir! The reason is that there is more flexibility when it comes to laying cells out in a Collection View as compared to a Table View (in I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Correct. But that flexibility comes into play when you have more than one column. In the 2nd image of what you want, you have a homogeneous list. Same cells, same width, same spacing, one column. This screams `UITableView`. You might be overcomplicating things

Comment: It is a little embarrassing but, can you do exactly the same I am trying to do by using a TableView? I thought it was only possible to customize cells (like rounding corners and adding spacing and some shading with a Collection View). I am still very new to this and I appreciate your advice!

Comment: I tend to agree with @Jesse here. The UITableView adds unnecessary restrictions. IMO that's just an UICollectionView. You should take a look to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout instead of LayoutDelegate, and build your own fancily wonderful layout by hand.

Comment: To respond to the second comment: it is possible, with "container" tableViewCell. You create your custom cell, sets a transparent background and adds your content view in the middle using constrains. However, if you want to move to a collection later one, keep in mind that you ll have to rewrite a whole lot of code. (it would create some quirks though, one I can think of is that if you tap on the edges, it would be recognized as the cell eventhoug you clicked outside. Can be dealt with but not really clean)

Answer (score 1):

In order to show a collection view cells as a list, you can change your cell width equals to the width of the collection view. Giving constant width will not work for different device size.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
       let width = collectionView.frame.width
     return CGSize(width: width, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

And give your desired constraint values for the inner rectangular view to achieve the desired look. Make collectionView cell background to clear.